# How to check if font or other product name has been used?

Tags: typefaces, font-design, resource-recommendations, trademark

I have used trademark searches before, such as http://www.uspto.gov/ but each country has their own, which means more searching than I have time for.  Besides many of those sites are incomplete, outdated, difficult to use, or all of the above.  Is there anything more reliable than a common web search plus the word "font" (or whatever your product will be)?

Comment: See it like this: If a reasonable web search returns no reasonable result, it is very unlikely that the name is already taken, let alone by somebody who cares enough about it to give you trouble. If you find something, even if it is not legally problematic, you probably want to choose another name for your product to guarantee that it’s the first thing that shows up on the web searches of other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything more reliable than a common web search plus the word "font" (or whatever your product will be)?

Not really. You can outsource the work to some 3rd party that can do this for you.

There is no central authority that can give you this info. Even exhaustive searches do not save you on a global scale. If web search is not good enough for you then you need to be prepared to send people to different countries. Even after this you can not be sure somebody can take the name meanwhile.

Comment: What are you saying "Not really" to? Some part of my question, or @Wrzlprmft 's comment?  And I am still not sure what you mean: outsource what work?  Looking into the legal aspects?

Comment: @Moscarda  "Is there anything more reliable than a common web search plus the word "font" (or whatever your product will be)?"

Comment: thanks for clarifying! I hate it when companies get sued for use of a name or for "brand dilution" even when they aren't even competitors or in the same industry, and the name in question is just a word, not something either should have rights to.